# Extracting <div data-v-xxx from HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape [this website](https://butik.mad.coop.dk/frugt-og-groent/groentsager/avocado/c-7) using json as described in the top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362598/how-to-extract-div-data-v-xxxxxxxx-div-from-html-using-beautifulsoup?newreg=cd9d68b0f9bb451c85a2a92851f3b657).

The specific code i'm trying to scrape is the following HTML code:

```
<div data-v-5005fea4 class="c-product-tile">
```

which contains code like:

```
<span data-v119c4757 class="major-price inline-block">25</span>
```

where i want to extract the 25 value.

My problem is that whether i use json or Beautifulsoup it returns 'None' and i don't know where to go from here

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like the HTML for those items is generated on the fly by Javascript. In that case you will need something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to get your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below **API** which returns output in `json` format.

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://butik.mad.coop.dk/api/search/search?categories=7&lastFacet=categories&pageSize=30").json()

for item in res['products']:
    print(item['displayName'])
    print(item['salesPrice']['amount'])
    print(item['salesPrice']['major'])
```

**Output**:

```
Avocado
25.0
25
Økologiske Avocado
19.95
19
Spisemodne Avocado
23.95
23
Økologiske Avocado
29.5
29
Avocado
9.5
9
```

---

To get the first item value.Use this.

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://butik.mad.coop.dk/api/search/search?categories=7&lastFacet=categories&pageSize=30").json()

print(res['products'][0]['salesPrice']['amount'])
print(res['products'][0]['salesPrice']['major'])
```

Comment: Thanks you! It was just what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, this data is loaded dynamically by Javascript; thus you cannot get it by static website fetching means.

You can install Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Then you would do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

driver = webdriver.firefox()
driver.get("https://butik.mad.coop.dk/frugt-og-groent/groentsager/avocado/c-7")   

soup = bs(driver.page_source,'lxml')
```

Then you'll see the data you're after:

```
In [17]: soup.find_all('span',{'class':"major-price inline-block"})
Out[17]: 
[<span class="major-price inline-block" data-v-119c4757="">25</span>,
 <span class="major-price inline-block" data-v-119c4757="">19</span>,
 <span class="major-price inline-block" data-v-119c4757="">23</span>,
 <span class="major-price inline-block" data-v-119c4757="">29</span>,
 <span class="major-price inline-block" data-v-119c4757="">9</span>]
```